# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que las flechas de input number me queden activas?

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que las flechas de incremento y decremento del `<input type="number">` me queden activas sin tener que posicionarme con el mouse sobre ellas para verlas (sin hacer *hover*)?

Es decir que se vea así por defecto como muestra la foto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<input type="number">
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar el pseudo-elemento **`-webkit-inner-spin-button`** especificando el input `input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button` para acceder al botón giratorio, y darle una opacidad de 1 de la siguiente forma:

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1">
```

Aquí te dejo una tabla de compatibilidad con los navegadores:

[image: Tabla de compatibilidad]

Espero te sirva.

Saludos ;)